# ASP.NET boolean radio buttons show up as unchecked

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, radio-button

I have the following two radio buttons with "Yes" and "No" labels which map to the boolean `AgreeToTerms`. Here is the HTML form:

```
    <div class="control">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AgreeToTerms)<br />
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.AgreeToTerms, true) Yes<br />
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.AgreeToTerms, false) No
    </div>
```

And here is the Model:

```
    [Display(Name = "Do you agree to the terms?")]
    public bool AgreeToTerms { get; set; }
```

When a new user submits a form and selects either radio button, then the `true` or `false` value is correctly set as the value of the `AgreeToTerms` boolean (I can confirm this in our SQL database). However, when an admin goes to review this form submitted by the user, the same HTML code above is used to display the form to the admin. The following screenshot is what the admin sees: two blank radio buttons:

[image]

And here is the generated HTML when `AgreeToTerms` is set to false:

```
    <div class="control">
        <label for="AgreeToTerms">Do you agree to the terms?</label><br />
        <input data-val="true" field" id="AgreeToTerms" name="AgreeToTerms" type="radio" value="True" /> Yes<br />
        <input checked="checked" id="AgreeToTerms" name="AgreeToTerms" type="radio" value="False" /> No
    </div>
```

And when `AgreeToTerms` is set to true:

```
    <div class="control">
        <label for="AgreeToTerms">Do you agree to the terms?</label><br />
        <input checked="checked" data-val="true" id="AgreeToTerms" name="AgreeToTerms" type="radio" value="True" /> Yes<br />
        <input id="AgreeToTerms" name="AgreeToTerms" type="radio" value="False" /> No
    </div>
```

**How can I get the radio buttons to display the true or false value of `AgreeToTerms`?**

Comment: As long as you set this property value in your GET action method, the helper will render the correct markup to select one of them based on the value of the property

Comment: You can set value of `AgreeToTerms` property in `HttpGet` action method (based on DB value in your case), see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vXTL7X) for example.